# How do I show a div, but make it completely un-interactive, in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `<div>` overlayed onto my page, and that tracks the mouse. However, on occasion the user is able to move the mouse at the appropriate speed to enter the tracking `<div>`. Also, this `<div>` will sometimes prevent the user from clicking something else, that is below/behind.

What is the correct way to visually show this `<div>`, without it 'blocking' or interfering with the underlying DOM, or any of them for that matter? In particular, to stop it interfering  with mouse events.

Comment: If I understand what you want to do correctly, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PsMs5/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good answers to this already, one you can consider also is the css:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Which effectively makes events act on the items below the div, not the div itself.

Support for this on IE isn't great, but it's a nice way if you either don't need IE support, or if you have the time to do it properly and include a conditional fallback.

Check out this for support info: http://caniuse.com/pointer-events

Comment: This achieved precisely what I needed.

Comment: interesting one +1 :-)

Answer (score 3):

you can place above it (with higher z-index) an absolute positioned `div` element, with an `opacity` value of 0

OR

you can use jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('#divId').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

i personally prefer the `opacity` approach. but that's me.

hope that helped

Comment: I need the DIV to be displayed. Are you suggesting I set it's opacity to 0? If so, surely this will visually hide hide the DIV?

Comment: no, i suggested placing ABOVE it a div with opacity of 0. so the invisible div will absorb the clicks

Answer (score 0):

Yuo can try to capture the event and prevent its default behavior using

```
event.preventDefault();
```

here a pseudo code, it works without jquery

```
var el = document.getElementById("yourdiv");
el.addEventListener("click", action, false);

function action() {
    event.preventDefault();
return false;
}
```